LIVEWIRE 3 Y DATA TABLES
tengo un componente livwire que renderiza una tabla con paginacion, cuando cargo la pagina la configuracion que ofrece datatable se activa, sin emabrgo cuando voy a la pagina 2 de mi tabla, esta no toma las funcionalidades de datatable, en mi caso uso la responsividad que este ofrece, esta es la parte logica de mi componente:
class ListarProductos extends Component
{   
    use WithPagination;
    protected $paginationTheme = "bootstrap";
    public function render()
    {   
        $producto = Producto::paginate(20);

        return view('livewire.productos.listar-productos', compact('producto'));
    }

    public function updatedPage()
    {
        $this->dispatch('refreshDataTable');
    }
}

y esto es lo que se renderiza:
@section('plugins.Datatables', true)
<div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="p-0 card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="lista_productos" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Opciones 1</th>
                            <th>Opciones 2</th>
                            <th>Opciones 3</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($producto as $item)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->nombre . ' ' . $item->caracteristicas }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->nombre . ' ' . $item->caracteristicas }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->nombre . ' ' . $item->caracteristicas }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $item->nombre . ' ' . $item->caracteristicas }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                    
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        {{ $producto->links() }}
    </div>
</div>

@script
    <script>
        
        new DataTable('#lista_productos', {
            info: false,
            ordering: false,
            paging: false,
            searching: false,
            responsive: true,
        });
        

        $wire.on('refreshDataTable', () => {
            $('#lista_productos').DataTable().destroy(true);
            
            new DataTable('#lista_productos', {
                info: false,
                ordering: false,
                paging: false,
                searching: false,
                responsive: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
@endscript

No entiendo porque no se ejecuta el datatable, ajuste la parte de scripts añadiendo un console.log y este si se muestra en la consola lo que significa que el evento si se esta recibiendo de manera correcta
